# how to load an english-site image, if the spanish-site-image does not exist

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, image, web

I have a multiple language site. With html, javascript, may be ajax if an image does not exist in spanish folder, it should load image from the english folder.

path example
english site : images/home.jpg
spanish site : es/images/home.jpg

Today i have message.properties ... stuff for doing text conversion 
message.properties
message_es.properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use onerror for the image

```
<img src="es/images/home.jpg" onerror="this.src='images/home.jpg'">
```

but, IMHO, it is better to do the job on server side

Comment: Clever. A pain if it's site-wide though.