# How do I test if image exists for a field in xslt?

Tags: image, xslt

I have a form where a field is an image which is uploaded, which works fine.  I now want to check to see if an image exists for that field and if not display a default no image

I have for now

```
<xsl:if test="fields/field_item_main_image/data/@original = ''"><span class="noimage"></span></xsl:if><xsl:copy-of select="fields/field_item_main_image/data" />
```

The span for no image simply provides a no image png file to be shown inplace of an image when none exists, but this is not working as the default image is not being shown, even though the field has no image assigned to it.

Looking at the source code the result is

```
 <data></data>
```

What am I doing wrong?

ADDITIONAL INFO

I'd like to add more info but really not sure what you want me to add to help me... let me know what is needed and I will see if I can get that info for you to help me.

The relevant class style is

```
.noimage {display:block;width:100px;height:100px;background-image: url(../images/no-image-available.png);}
```

This is related to SobiPro a Joomla Compontent

Here is the form code

```
<div>               
            <xsl:for-each select="entry/fields/*">
                <xsl:if test="( name() != 'save_button' ) and ( name() != 'cancel_button' )">
                    <xsl:variable name="fieldId">
                        <xsl:value-of select="data/*/@id" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <div id="{$fieldId}Container">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="position() mod 2">spFormRowEven</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>spFormRowOdd</xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:if test="string-length( fee )">
                            <div class="spFormPaymentInfo">
                                <input name="{$fieldId}Payment" id="{$fieldId}Payment" value="" type="checkbox" class="SPPaymentBox" onclick="SP_ActivatePayment( this )"/>                             
                                <label for="{$fieldId}Payment">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="fee_msg"></xsl:value-of><br/>
                                </label>
                                <div style="margin-left:20px;">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="php:function( 'SobiPro::Txt', 'TP.PAYMENT_ADD' )" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <div class="spFormRowLeft">
                            <label for="{$fieldId}">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="string-length( description )">
                                        <xsl:variable name="desc">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="description" />
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:variable name="label">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="label" />
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="php:function( 'SobiPro::Tooltip', $desc, $label )" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>                                        
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="label"/>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>                               
                            </label>
                        </div>                                          
                        <div class="spFormRowRight">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="data/@escaped">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="data" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="data/*" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>                                                   
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@suffix"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </xsl:if>           
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
```

As part of the input one of my fields is an image field, it is that field I am wanting to check to see if a user has uploaded an image to that field, if they have then show that image, if not then show a default no image.

Does any of this help?

GW

Comment: Are you saying that the XSLT transformation, which you haven't shown, when applied on the XML document, which you haven't shown, produces an output, which you havent shown that isn't the output you want, which you haven't shown?

Comment: @Dimitre: LOL.. user664086: you need to at least show us the input to the stylesheet (or at least the relevant piece of it) and tell us what you think the context node is at the point where your `<xsl:if>` is being processed. One possibility is that you are testing for an attribute that exists but has an empty string value, whereas you need to test for that attribute to not exist. But we won't know till you show us the input.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess my answer to yours is I am not sure I understand what you are asking for. I am 'NEW' to this so have a case of very little understanding

Answer (score 1):

If the default image for that field does not change, then I would do all of this on the client side.

[Take a look at this answer to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864819/how-to-load-an-english-site-image-if-the-spanish-site-image-does-not-exist)

Comment: Yes I had seen that before but it was not quite what I was looking for.